# Specifying lag in `dlnm` when passing arguments to `crossbasis`

Tags: r, multiple-regression, modeling, lags

I am using the `dlnm` package to build a finite distribute lag linear model. I intend on testing the model-fit based on various lag levels to assess which lag is suitable. Needless to mention I will apply some domain knowledge to make a good call. I am using these two available resources to carry out this rather complex exercise: 
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3191524/

http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dlnm/vignettes/dlnmOverview.pdf

I first created a Matrix to include non-linear effects of both my predictors using this: 
`ImpressionsA.x<-onebasis(locanatmodelset$ImpressionsA.x, fun="poly", degree=2)`
`ImpressionsA.y<-onebasis(locanatmodelset$ImpressionsA.y, fun="poly", degree=2)`

Since my non-linear relationship is tending to be quadratic, I am using 2nd degree polynomials. Now I need to factor in the lags for each variable by calling `crossbasis`. This is where I am confused. The function as per the package documentation is of the format: 
`cb <- crossbasis(chicagoNMMAPS$temp,lag=30,argvar=list("thr",thr.value=c(10,20)),
arglag=list(knots=c(1,4,12)))`

my doubts are :

1) in `lag=30` is 30 of the same units as my response variable or will it be in the units of my predictor variable? In my case, my lag is specified in days. I want to specify 5 days as lag before fitting the model. How should I pass the argument?

2) Since I have already created my basis matrix for predictor variables using `onebasis`, how should I pass the arguments `argvar` and `arglag`?

3) I also wanted to extract the lagged values of my predictor variables (ImpressionsA.x and ImpressionsA.y) in their original units. The matrix itself is not helpful. It transforms everything into negative values on some other scale all together.

Comment: The $y=x1*x2$ formula is shorthand for $y=x1+x2+x1:x2$. That is, it introduces the interaction between the two variables. Not sure if you're confusing autocorrelation and correlation: autocorrelation is correlation of a variable with lagged versions of itself. ("Auto" = "Self")

Comment: thanks Wayne. Apologies for wrong usage of concepts & terms. I am reading http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3191524/ and its very insightful on how dlnm should be used for lag models. I might self answer after reading it.

Comment: @Wayne I've made edits based on my progress with the work so far.

Comment: You mention that you are doing a "finite distribute lag linear model".  Has an "infinite" DLNM ever been proposed?

Comment: Please look up Koyck Model or Geometric Lags.

Comment: @zkurtz, an example of an "infinite" dlm shows up here as equation 3: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10182-006-0221-5#

Comment: This question seems to be cross-posted:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984893/specifying-lag-in-dlnm-when-passing-arguments-to-crossbasis

Comment: Yes, why is that a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will likely be an iterative process, because you may want to rephrase your question as things become more clear.

1) In your usage, the first argument to `crossbasis` is a vector.  According to `?crossbasis`, as a vector it needs to represent "a complete series of ordered observations".  You said that your time units are days.  Thus, presumably, `lag = 30` means that you'll be looking back 1 day, 2 days, ..., 30 days simultaneously.  With `dlnm`, you never fit individual lags.  You fit the whole range of lags.  If you are particularly interested in the 5th lag, maybe you want to use `lag = 8` or so and then see if the estimated effect for the fifth lag stands out as being bigger than the effects for the other lags.  NOTE:  The whole idea of the word "distributed" in `dlnm` is that the lagged effect of a variable is literally distributed across several lags, or even fractions of lags.

2) The `crossbasis` function does not accept the output of `onebasis` as an argument; it's just not set up that way.  Instead, you pass in your arguments to `onebasis` through `argvar=list(), arglag=list()` in `crossbasis`, which calls `onebasis` *internally*.  In particular, if you do `crossbasis(locanatmodelset$ImpressionsA.x, lag = 8,...`, then `crossbasis` will actually go and call `onebasis` two times, once to make a basis for `locanatmodelset$ImpressionsA.x` and once to make a basis for the lags `[0,1, ...,8]`.

3) Clarify what you mean here.  If you want to "extract the lagged value" of any vector element, say the kth element of a vector x, you just do `x[k-L]` to get the Lth lag.  No special `R` package is necessary.